# Is there any possible way a visitor can access what is sent by POST?

Tags: php, post

is it safe to send any kind of information i dont want the visitor to see through POST? 
are there known ways visitors can hack and see the POSTed information. 
(im thinking browser plugins, browser hacks)

Comment: No. Yes. Anything else? Using SSL encryption (https://) will alleviate this problem. SSL is still subject to "Man-in-the-Middle" attacks, but it makes sensitive data much, much more difficult to access.

Comment: For a bit more, here's [a discussion from the PHP chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3048326#3048326) from yesterday on a similar topic.

Answer (score 0):

Dude - anything that's sent in clear text can be seen by anybody who wants to look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

If the visitor is posting the data from your form then they can always see the data from show source in the browser. The only way to hide what is being sent is to encrypt the data in the form.